# Raspbian: wlan connection doesn't work after disconnecting ethernet cable

Tags: raspbian, wifi

on my Pi model 2b I connected a ethernet cable and an edimax n300 wifi usb dongle. I want to use the Pi over WLAN so I attached the WLAN dongle to the Pi and configured them with the following additional configuration in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ap-scan 1
wpa-scan-ssid 1
wpa-ssid "RouterName"
wpa-psk "***************"
```

After restarting the networking all worked fine. The new IP address that the Pi received from the router is pingable. Also in the console of the router I see the Pi with the additional IP and MAC address.
If I disconnect the ethernet channel I cannot ping the new IP of the WLAN interface. Also SSH is not possible. When I connect the ethernet cable again to the Pi it works fine (ping,SSH,...).

I tested both: dhcp and static IP

Are there some other config steps necessary? Did someone also had this problems?

Thanks

Comment: Putting **ANYTHING** in /etc/network/interfaces will break networking!

Comment: `If I disconnect the ethernet channel I cannot ping the new IP of the WLAN interface` ... probably because the ping is being routed over ethernet cable .... wlan is probably not transferring any data at all